# .NET Core 2.0 Avro CodeGenerator cannot handle nested structures or IDL

Tags: c#, .net-core, avro

I am trying to use the `Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Utils` library in a C# .NET Core 2.0 application to generate C# class for my Avro schema, but I cannot get it to handle nested records when creating a simple Avro JSON schema.

In general, I would much more like to use the Avro IDL format to describe my data structure as it is a bit complex and I am reusing my records different places. I have tried finding documentation on the .NET Core Avro library with no luck and I cannot see if it is even possible to auto generate complex structures in the C# library.

Do anyone have experience with this library or how to auto generate C# classes for Avro. Below is a very simple example of an Avro schema that I cannot get nested `Address` class into the final output.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Person",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Address",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "zipcode",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```